# Ghostview with special character passwords

Tags: passwords, ghostscript

I have a PDF that I'd like to archive password-less. I don't have the master password, but I do have the viewing password. In the past, I've used ghostview to do this. In this case, though, the password has ]`%!|&; in it.

I've tried escaping at the shell with \ but it doesn't work. I've tried entering it at the interactive prompt. That also fails. Suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Have you tried enclosing in quotes? 2. Ghost*script* can compose a string and pass it in as an argument: https://ghostscript.com/docs/9.54.0/Use.htm#Invoking , e.g., -dname=string, -sname=string or -pname=string , for various types of entry.

Comment: If you are using Ghostview then you must be using an old version of Ghostscript (because Ghostview no longer works with recent versions of Ghostscript). You should try using Ghostscript itself.